# How to connect react native saga to react native firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, redux-saga, react-native-firebase

I have these sagas, But I am getting unsubscribe everytime on channel and failure action. What is the reason? I am using React Native Firebase and RNFirestore

```js
 function firebaseChannel(userId) {
  const ref = database
    .collection("chat_rooms")
    .where("metadata.members." + userId, ">", 0)
    .orderBy("metadata.members." + userId, "desc")

  const channel = eventChannel(emit => {
    const unsubscribe = ref.onSnapshot(emit)
    // Returns unsubscribe function
    return unsubscribe
  })
  return channel
}

export function* sync() {
  const userId = getUserId()
  const channel = yield call(firebaseChannel, userId)

  try {
    while (true) {
      const data = yield take(channel);
      yield fork(successActionCreator(data, userId));
    }
  } catch (err) {
    // yield fork(failureActionCreator(err))
    console.tron.log("Failure", err)
  }
  finally {
    // if (yield cancelled()) {
    //   channel.close();
    // }
  }
}
```

Comment: If your `catch` gets called, what is the `err` that you get?

Comment: There is nothing about firebase in the errorline:208788
column:55
sourceURL:http://localhost:8081/index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false